# Modify regex to allow for additional urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, youtube, vimeo

I have tried everything with my regex, but I can't seem to adapt this for my new URL's, it's just not working for me.

Please see my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/693y7/

Basically I need to extract the video id from each url, and also determine if it's youtube or video, it determines it's location just fine, however the ID doesn't work on all urls.

I didn't write this regex, however I have tried adding in users, additional or operators to try and find alternate results, but I'm just not getting anywhere, would someone mind helping me better understand how to approach the new urls that aren't working in the demo?

URLS:

```
var urls = [
    "//player.vimeo.com/video/84687115",
    "http://player.vimeo.com/video/25451551",
    "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg&feature=feedrec_grec_index",
    "http://www.youtube.com/user/usernamehere#p/a/u/1/QdK8U-VIH_o",
    "http://www.youtube.com/v/0zM3nApSvMg?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0",
    "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg#t=0m10s",
    "http://www.youtube.com/embed/0zM3nApSvMg?rel=0",
    "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg",
    "https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/My2FRPA3Gf8",
    "http://youtu.be/0zM3nApSvMg",
    "http://vimeo.com/84687115",
    "http://vimeo.com/channels//84687115",
    "http://vimeo.com/groups//videos/84687115"
];
```

Here's the function I'm using to match the ID's

```
function parseVideo(url) {

    url.match(/(http:|https:|)\/\/(player.|www.)?(vimeo\.com|youtu(be\.com|\.be|be\.googleapis\.com))\/(video\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|v\/|user\/)?([A-Za-z0-9._%-]*)(\&\S+)?/);

    if (RegExp.$3.indexOf('youtu') > -1) {
        var type = 'youtube';
    } else if (RegExp.$3.indexOf('vimeo') > -1) {
        var type = 'vimeo';
    }

    return {
        type: type,
        id: RegExp.$6
    };
}
```

I hope this is enough information!

Comment: You need to extend the matcher for the middle of the url to also allow "channels//" and "groups//" as valid values http://jsfiddle.net/693y7/1/

Comment: Thankyou @LJ_1102 that got everything with the exception of the url with the user in it (4th url in array)

Comment: A great tool to debug regular expressions is rubular.com, not only for ruby regexes

Comment: Also may I introduce you to a way simpler approach?
http://jsfiddle.net/693y7/2/

Comment: wow @LJ_1102 That is very very simple and elegant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend the matcher for the middle of the url to also allow
"channels//" and "groups//" as valid values jsfiddle.net/693y7/1

```
/(http:|https:|)\/\/(player.|www.)?(vimeo\.com|youtu(be\.com|\.be|be\.googleapis\.com))\/(video\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|v\/|user\/|channels\/\/|groups\/\/videos\/)?([A-Za-z0-9._%-]*)(\&\S+)?/
```

As you've pointed out this still does not work for the 4th URL in your example.
To also support this url you would need to add an additional matching group matching "a/u/1", or in regex

```
(\/a\/u\/\d)?
```

As i've pointed out in the comments it might be simpler to use a non regex approach,
assuming that video ids are always at the end of the url only followed by some meta parameters one could use the following approach http://jsfiddle.net/693y7/2/

```
var sres = url.split("/");
var dirtyid = sres[sres.length-1];
return dirtyid.replace("watch?v=", "").split(/&|#|\?/)[0];
```

This approach just splits the url by its slashes, then taking the last part containing the videoid and meta parameters and using some simple replace and split operations to obtain the wanted video id.

While this approach may not be the cleanest its easy to extend and adjust for new usecases, url types and is probably more robust than such a large regex.

To obtain the service type one could simply do an indexof check on "youtu" and/or "vimeo".

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `channels` and `groups` to the regex, and you also need to allow for more than one consecutive `/` in the url:

`url.match(/(http:|https:|)\/\/(player.|www.)?(vimeo\.com|youtu(be\.com|\.be|be\.googleapis\.com))\/(video\/*|embed\/*|watch\?v=|v\/*|user\/*|channels\/*|groups\/*)?([A-Za-z0-9._%-]*)(\&\S+)?/);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better off to use multiple regular expressions.  In fact, I'd probably set things up so that you have one regular expression per expected format which does two things: 1) definitely identifies it as a certain format, and 2) places a matching group around the desired portions.  If you put them all in an array, you can write some code which loops through them and stops when it finds the first one which matches.

```
patterns = [ ... ] // all your different regexes
for (regex in patterns) {
    if (url.match(regex)) {
        // Grab the variables you need and return them.
    }
}
```